# Discord.js A bot That Say Something in a Channel user Chooses

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So basically I try to write some code that when the user type .say "message" in #general the bot will go to #general channel and say "message"

I tried working on that code so much, but I don't know how to assign a channel for the bot to say the message in

```
`bot.on('message', message => {
    const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
    if(message.content.startsWith('.say')) {
        message.delete()
        var saytext = args.join(" ");
        message.channel.send(saytext)
    };
  } )`
```

So the code is working when I type .say and whatever comes after it the bot say it in the channel the user said the code, but what I want is to make the bot send the message in another channel not the same channel. I mean if the server have #general and #Music and the user was in #general and just typed .say I love music in #Music the bot will say "I love music in #Music" not "I love music" in "#music".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `message.channel.send` , which makes the bot answer in the same channel the message was sent, you need to retrieve the specified channel.
To achieve this, you can use `message.mentions.channels` to detect which channel(s) have been mentionned in your command.

Here is an example of how you can do this. Please also note that in my case, I made it work with a command like : `.say <#channel> <message>`, this syntax is easier to parse than the one you asked for.

In your case, you'll have to type ".say #Music I love music." in any channel the bot has access to.

```
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(".say")) {
      // Get the channel mention
      if (message.mentions.channels.size == 0) {
          message.reply("please mention a channel first.");
      }
      else {
          let targetChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
          // Get the message to print

          const args = message.content.split(" ").slice(2);
          let saytext = args.join(" ");
          targetChannel.send(saytext);
          message.delete();
      }
});
```